# GLM coefficients from caret - Machine Learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have a quick question I can't seem to find a good answer to, so I hope this makes sense and please let me know of any important information I may leave out.

I've been using the machine learning functions of caret recently and have the below syntax:

```
controlroc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 5,
                           savePredictions = "final",
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           selectionFunction = "oneSE", 
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, allowParallel = TRUE )

set.seed(1234)

model_listworks <- caretList(
  DV ~., 
  data = train,
  trControl=controlroc,
  metric="ROC",
  tuneList=list( 
    glmmodel = caretModelSpec(method="glm", family = "binomial"),
    enetmodel=caretModelSpec(method="glmnet", tuneGrid = expand.grid (alpha = c (0, .1, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1), lambda = seq (.01, .2, length = 40))),
    rfmodel = caretModelSpec(method="rf", tuneGrid = expand.grid (.mtry=c(1:10)), ntrees = 1000)
  ) 
)
```

This has worked really well but now I'm trying to pull some basic GLM coefficients produced in the model_listworks. The syntax used to grab my GLM coefficients is relatively simple:

```
coef(model_listworks$glmmodel$finalModel)
```

The problem I seem to be having is that I can't identify if these coefficients are standardized (they appear to be based on visual inspection) and further, if they are standardized via the IV or DV. I do find this funny as the rest of this process was generally seamless, but now I can't seem to find the appropriate sources.

Answer (score 1):

They are not standardized since you did not specify `preProcess=..` when training the model. Using an example dataset:

```
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)
set.seed(1234)

train = iris
train$DV = factor(ifelse(train$Species == "versicolor","v","o"))
train$Species=NULL

model_listworks <- caretList(
  DV ~., 
  data = train,
  trControl=controlroc,
  metric="ROC",
  tuneList=list( 
    glmmodel = caretModelSpec(method="glm", family = "binomial"),
    enetmodel=caretModelSpec(method="glmnet", tuneGrid = expand.grid (alpha = c (0, .1, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1), lambda = seq (.01, .2, length = 40))),
    rfmodel = caretModelSpec(method="rf", tuneGrid = expand.grid (.mtry=c(1:3)), ntrees = 100)
  ) 
)

 coef(model_listworks$glmmodel$finalModel)
 (Intercept) Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   7.3784866   -0.2453567   -2.7965681    1.3136433   -2.7783439
```

Check this against if you would just fit a linear model:

```
coef(glm(DV ~ .,data=train,family="binomial"))
 (Intercept) Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   7.3784866   -0.2453567   -2.7965681    1.3136433   -2.7783439
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one follow-up question then. Once I add preProcess option, this would standardize the features/IV, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct